# Netbeans custom inno setup throws error while creating exe file

Tags: netbeans, inno-setup

While creating exe file using inno setup in `Netbeans 7.3.1` if i do a custom iss file in `package/windows` folder, i am getting this error message. I have written this line inside the TimeTracker.iss:

```
[UninstallDelete]
Type: filesandordirs; Name: "{usercf}\timetracker"
```

```
Result application bundle: D:\Project\TimeTracker\dist\bundles
java.io.IOException: Exec failed with code 2 command [[iscc.exe, /oD:\Project\TimeTracker\dist\bundles, C:\Users\dsingh\AppData\Local\Temp\build5274695928588461589.fxbundler\images\win-app.image\TimeTracker.iss] in C:\Users\dsingh\AppData\Local\Temp\build5274695928588461589.fxbundler\images\win-app.image
at com.sun.javafx.tools.packager.bundlers.IOUtils.exec(IOUtils.java:131)
at com.sun.javafx.tools.packager.bundlers.IOUtils.exec(IOUtils.java:107)
at com.sun.javafx.tools.packager.bundlers.IOUtils.exec(IOUtils.java:101)
at com.sun.javafx.tools.packager.bundlers.WinExeBundler.buildEXE(WinExeBundler.java:324)
at com.sun.javafx.tools.packager.bundlers.WinExeBundler.bundle(WinExeBundler.java:144)
at com.sun.javafx.tools.packager.PackagerLib.generateNativeBundles(PackagerLib.java:527)
at com.sun.javafx.tools.packager.PackagerLib.generateDeploymentPackages(PackagerLib.java:506)
at com.sun.javafx.tools.ant.DeployFXTask.execute(DeployFXTask.java:234)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:75)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor12.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:279)
at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:165)
at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.NativeJavaMethod.call(NativeJavaMethod.java:245)
at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.Interpreter.interpretLoop(Interpreter.java:1706)
at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:849)
at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:162)
at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:433)
at com.sun.script.javascript.RhinoScriptEngine$1.superDoTopCall(RhinoScriptEngine.java:116)
at com.sun.script.javascript.RhinoScriptEngine$1.access$200(RhinoScriptEngine.java:71)
at com.sun.script.javascript.RhinoScriptEngine$1$1.run(RhinoScriptEngine.java:105)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.script.javascript.RhinoScriptEngine$1.doTopCall(RhinoScriptEngine.java:103)
at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3161)
at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.InterpretedFunction.exec(InterpretedFunction.java:173)
at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.Context.evaluateReader(Context.java:1159)
at com.sun.script.javascript.RhinoScriptEngine.eval(RhinoScriptEngine.java:214)
at com.sun.script.javascript.RhinoScriptEngine.eval(RhinoScriptEngine.java:240)
at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(AbstractScriptEngine.java:264)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.tools.ant.util.ReflectUtil.invoke(ReflectUtil.java:108)
at org.apache.tools.ant.util.ReflectWrapper.invoke(ReflectWrapper.java:81)
at org.apache.tools.ant.util.optional.JavaxScriptRunner.evaluateScript(JavaxScriptRunner.java:103)
at org.apache.tools.ant.util.optional.JavaxScriptRunner.executeScript(JavaxScriptRunner.java:67)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.Script.execute(Script.java:52)
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor94.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor94.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.MacroInstance.execute(MacroInstance.java:398)
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor94.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:392)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:413)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(SingleCheckExecutor.java:38)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:442)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.CallTarget.execute(CallTarget.java:105)
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor94.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:392)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:413)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(SingleCheckExecutor.java:38)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:442)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.CallTarget.execute(CallTarget.java:105)
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor94.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:392)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:413)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
at org.apache.tools.ant.module.bridge.impl.BridgeImpl.run(BridgeImpl.java:283)
at org.apache.tools.ant.module.run.TargetExecutor.run(TargetExecutor.java:541)
at org.netbeans.core.execution.RunClassThread.run(RunClassThread.java:153)
```

Comment: The full Java stack trace is irrelevant here. It's just reporting that `iscc.exe` exited with an exit code of 2.

Answer (score 2):

This simply comes down to `iscc.exe` exited with code 2, which according to the [documentation](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=compilercmdline) means "compile failed".

The best way to find out why is to run that command directly and see what happens.
If that works, then you will need to try and get the output (stdout) of the command to see what it reported.

Answer (score 1):

Is `Inno Setup 5.5 or more recent` installed and added to the Windows path. Please restart your IDE after installing the above tools.

Answer (score 0):

I have same errors with build project in Eclipse. I just change install path of Inno Setup and delete all spaces, fix PATH enviroment and restart IDE.

**From:**

```
C:\Java\Software\Inno Setup 5
```

**To:**

```
C:\Java\Software\InnoSetup5
```